# How to use iOS delegate and callback methods from NMSSH library?

Tags: ios, delegates, nmssh

I'm trying to use delegate methods from NMSSH library in iOS but could not get it working. Let's take an example.

**CustomViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <NMSSH/NMSSH.h>

@interface CustomViewController : UIViewController<NMSSHSessionDelegate, NMSSHChannelDelegate>

- (IBAction)connectButton:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

**CustomViewController.m**

```
#import "CustomViewController.h"

@implementation CustomViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)connectButton:(UIButton *)sender {

        [self serverConnect:@"10.0.0.1"];

}

-(void)serverConnect:(NSString *)address{

NMSSHSession *session = [NMSSHSession connectToHost:address withUsername:@"username"];

NMSSHChannel *myChannel = [[NMSSHChannel alloc]init];

    if (session.isConnected) {
        [session authenticateByPassword:@"password"];

        if (session.isAuthorized) {
            NSLog(@"Authentication succeeded");
            [session setDelegate:self];
        [myChannel setDelegate:self];
        }
    }

        NSError *error = nil;
        //session.channel.requestPty = YES; (tried and later ignored)
        NSString *response = [session.channel execute:@"mkdir" error:&error];
        NSLog(@"Response from device: %@", response);
}

- (void)session:(NMSSHSession *)session didDisconnectWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"log if session disconnects...Delegate method");
}

- (void)channel:(NMSSHChannel *)channel didReadError:(NSString *)error{
    NSLog(@"Error received...Delegate method");
}

- (void)channel:(NMSSHChannel *)channel didReadRawData:(NSData *)data{
    NSLog(@"Read Raw Data...Delegate method");
}
```

Connection to the server, sending a single line command and acknowledgement back from the server in Console is OK.

I have decent idea how to pass values from one View Controller to another using delegate (went through few tutorials with practical implementation).

With the same knowledge I am attempting to get response from delegate methods parts of NMSSH library but it's driving me round and round. I've found http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/NMSSH/2.2.1/ pretty nice API of this library but with my limited knowledge of iOS, I'm bit stuck.

Please help me.

Comment: Did you make sure if (session.isAuthorized) { is returning true and the lines within the condition is getting executed?

Since you set delegate within the if, make sure they are getting executed.

Comment: [session.channel execute:@"command" error:&error];
NSLog(@"Response from device: %@", response);

I can confirm on server, the command is being executed and in iOS Console the response coming back from server. Hence session.authorized is working with no issues. 

I also tried few more combination setting delegate outside session.authorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My search finally came to an end with NMSSH AsyncAPI (branch) which supports multithreading.

Comment: I am trying to use the the NMSSH AsyncAPI but I am not able to connect or upload files to SFTP. For you was it worked? I tried using cocoa pods and adding manually as build also.

Comment: It worked for me indeed. As I recollect I built (downloaded project) from github, compiled (though there were errors) and pulled (drag & drop) the NMSSH AsyncAPI package to my new project.